# extract start and end of time interval based on a given date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

For a `df` column with dates (all in the past), I need to replace two columns with start and end dates surrounding given date.  For each `df` row, there are two columns with current (relative to today`2021-4-9`) start and end dates that could be either of the two exact six month intervals below:

```
2020-11-15  2021-5-15
2021-2-15   2021-8-15
```

*Example*:  if one of the days in the past was `1995-06-01`, the columns with intervals would need to contain either `1995-05-15  1995-11-15` or `1995-02-15  1995-08-15` depending on months in the current interval.

#### have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-6-10', '1995-6-1', '2013-10-12'],
                   'current_start_date': ['2020-11-15', '2020-11-15', '2021-2-15'],
                   'current_end_date': ['2021-5-15', '2021-5-15', '2021-8-15']})

df[['date', 'current_start_date', 'current_end_date']] = df[['date', 'current_start_date', 'current_end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

#### need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2016-6-10', '1995-6-1', '2013-10-12'],
                   'original_start_date': ['2016-5-15', '1995-5-15', '2013-8-15'],
                    'original_end_date': ['2016-11-15', '1995-11-15', '2014-2-15']})

df[['date', 'original_start_date', 'original_end_date']] = df[['date', 'original_start_date', 'original_end_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: From your given data, I think you only need to replace the year part of `current_start/end_date` and swap that two columns.

Comment: yes, but, for the past date of 1995-12-01 the interval should be 1995-11-15 to 1996-5-15, i.e., different past interval but the same current interval

Comment: Could you explain the logic here, how to generate interval from past date?

Comment: there are two types of exact 6 month intervals, the only difference are months not days, one is May 15 to Nov 15 to May 15 of next year and so on. The other is Feb 15 to Aug 15 to Feb 15 of next year.

Comment: In `1995-06-01` example, why do you choose `1995-05-15  1995-11-15` rather than `1995-02-15  1995-08-15` at last.

Comment: because these are the months in row 2 of my current interval in **have** `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your interval is kind of hardcode, I just use the following script

```py
def create_original_date(row):
    year = row['date'].year
    months = [row['current_start_date'].month, row['current_end_date'].month]
    l = min(months)
    h = max(months)

    interval = pd.Interval(pd.Timestamp(f'{year}-{l}-15'),
                           pd.Timestamp(f'{year}-{h}-15'),
                           closed='left')

    if row['date'] in interval:
        return interval.left, interval.right
    elif row['date'].month <= l:
        return interval.right.replace(year=year-1), interval.left
    else:
        return interval.right, interval.left.replace(year=year+1)

df[['original_start_date', 'original_end_date']] = df.apply(create_original_date, axis=1, result_type='expand')

df.drop(['current_start_date', 'current_end_date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

```
# print(df)

        date original_start_date original_end_date
0 2016-06-10           2016-05-15        2016-11-15
1 1995-06-01           1995-05-15        1995-11-15
2 2013-10-12           2013-08-15        2014-02-15
```

The idea is that values in `date` column must belong to interval `1`, `2` or `3`.

```
date
yy-mm-dd  {yy-1}-11-15  {yy}-05-15  {yy}-11-15  {yy+1}-05-15
yy-mm-dd  {yy-1}-08-15  {yy}-02-15  {yy}-08-15  {yy+1}-02-15
          |              |     |      |    |               |
           ------1-------       ---2--      ------3--------
```

The logic of my algorithm is

1. If `date` is in interval `2`, it belongs to interval `2`.
2. If not, check the month of date `mm`

   2.1 If `mm` <= 05/02, it belongs to interval `1`.

   2.2 Otherwise, it belongs to interval `3`.

Comment: wish i could split it, but unfortunately awarded to @tdy due to vectorization mainly. I like `pd.Interval` idea

Answer (score 1):

This can be vectorized into 3 lines with [**`np.sort()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

1. `sort` the start/end date pairs (reset to the same year to only consider month/day)
2. `where` the `date` occurs before start date, swap the start/end dates and decrement the start year
3. `where` the `date` occurs after end date, swap the start/end dates and increment the end year

```py
date = lambda Y, m: pd.to_datetime(Y.astype(str) + m.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '15')
    
#1 sort start/end date pairs (axis=0)
df[['current_start_date', 'current_end_date']] = pd.DataFrame(np.sort([
    date(df.date.dt.year, df.current_start_date.dt.month),
    date(df.date.dt.year, df.current_end_date.dt.month),
], axis=0).T)

#2 where date occurs before start date, swap and decrement start year
df['original_start_date'], df['original_end_date'] = np.where(df.date < df.current_start_date,
    [df.current_end_date - pd.DateOffset(years=1), df.current_start_date],
    [df.current_start_date, df.current_end_date])

#3 where date occurs after end date, swap and increment end year
df['original_start_date'], df['original_end_date'] = np.where(df.date > df.current_end_date,
    [df.current_end_date, df.current_start_date + pd.DateOffset(years=1)],
    [df.original_start_date, df.original_end_date])

df = df.drop(columns=['current_start_date', 'current_end_date'])

#         date  original_start_date  original_end_date
# 0 2016-06-10           2016-05-15         2016-11-15
# 1 1995-06-01           1995-05-15         1995-11-15
# 2 2013-10-12           2013-08-15         2014-02-15
# 3 1998-12-01           1998-11-15         1999-05-15
# 4 1998-01-01           1997-11-15         1998-05-15
# 5 1998-05-14           1997-11-15         1998-05-15
# 6 1998-05-16           1998-05-15         1998-11-15
# 7 1990-11-15           1990-05-15         1990-11-15
```

This is much faster than [**`df.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

[image: df.apply() vs np.where()]

Comment: I just fix the issue you mentioned. BTW, look at your algorithm description, it seems you didn't consider the day. Don't know if it is right using `05-14` and `05-16`.

Comment: Good point, no idea why I only checked the month. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

ended up with

```
start_mo = pd.DataFrame([df['current_start_date'].dt.month,
                         df['current_end_date'].dt.month]).min()

df['original_start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DataFrame(
                    {'year': df['date'].dt.year,            
                     'month': start_mo,
                     'day': pd.Series(15,index=df.index)}))         

td = pd.DateOffset(months=6)    
df.loc[df['date'] <  df['original_start_date'], 'original_start_date'] = df['original_start_date'] - td
df.loc[df['date'] >=  df['original_start_date'] + td, 'original_start_date'] =  df['original_start_date'] + td
df['original_oed_date'] = df['original_start_date'] + td
```

`df.loc` is faster than `np.where` and heavily relied on `pd.DateOffset`